# expression must have class type error c++

Tags: c++

So I have this defined:

```
static  char    randomstring[128];
```

Now whenever I mention it somewhere like so:

```
char *x = randomstring;
```

It goes fine but whenever I try to do something with its content:

```
char *x = ranomstring.front();
```

It doesn't work at all and says expression must have class type..
This problem occurs a LOT for me.
I should also mention I'm a total noob at c++.

Comment: An array of `char` is not an instance of a class. It doesn't have methods to call. Read a C++ book if you're a beginner, don't waste our (and your own) time.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably learn the difference betwenn [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) (a class) and [c-style string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) (`char*` or `char[]` - array).

```
//this calls std::string constructor to convert c-style string to std::string:
string mystring = "hello world!";
//std::string has front()
char* front = mystring.front();
//this is old-style string
char oldstring[] = "hello again!";
//you can access it as pointer, not as class
char* first = oldstring;
//but you can iterate both
for(char c : mystring) cout << c;
for(char c : oldstring) cout << c;
//...because it uses std::begin which is specialized for arrays
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C++ are not classes. They are aggregates. So they have no methods.
Use instead either standard container `std::string` or standard container `std::vector` that can dynamically change their sizes and have method `front`.

For example

```
#include <string>

//...

std::string randomstring;

//filling the string

char x = randomstring.front();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change char *x = ranomstring.front(); 
To char *x = ((string)ranomstring).front();